# How to clone a blob in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm desperately trying to clone a [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) in javascript without using an external library (such as jQuery).

I've tried `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(blob))` without success.

Comment: Please elaborate on "blob".

Comment: Did you try what is suggested in the docs you linked to? *"To create a blob that contains a subset of another blob's data, use the slice() method"*

Comment: @FelixKling I've added a link to the blob word. In my case the blob is a pdf but I don't think it has an influence on the question...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the documentation:

> To create a blob that contains a subset of another blob's data, use the `slice()` method.

So you could probably use

```
var copy = blob.slice();
```

It also says

> To construct a Blob from other non-blob objects and data, use the Blob() constructor.

and looking at the constructors documentation's suggests that the following should work as well:

```
var copy = new Blob([blob], {type: blob.type});
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that the accepted answer doesn’t clone the underlying data, it creates another reference to it. So does `new Blob([myBlob])`. This is usually what you want, because it avoids creating extra copies of the file in memory, which can be expensive at common filesizes. However, since `File` objects also are references not copies, this results in behavior like the following:

1. User uploads a file
2. You receive the file, clone it, possibly display it to the user to show you really have it
3. User deletes, renames, or moves the original file
4. Your copy of the file vanishes

To avoid this, you need to actually clone the underlying data, which you can do with this function.

```
const cloneBlob = b => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const r = new FileReader();
  r.readAsArrayBuffer(b);

  r.addEventListener('load', _ => {
    resolve(new Blob([r.result], {type: b.type}));
  });

  r.addEventListener('error', _ => {
    reject();
  });
});
```